# Azure Function CLI commands

Tags: azure, azure-functions, wkhtmltopdf

I'm looking to use wkhtmltopdf with an Azure Function in Python, and apparently I need to install wkhtmltopdf:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

As far as best practices go, would I want to use the Azure-CLI library to run these every time I evoke the function? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Can you explain about this: 'would I want to use the Azure-CLI library to run these every time I evoke the function'

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking the wrong questions.

Comment: @RobertRiley How did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not and I have written this problem off for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look of this python developer doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python

And use requirements.txt to install the package you want to install.

The structure should be like this:

```
__app__
 | - my_first_function
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - my_second_function
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - shared_code
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 | - host.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - Dockerfile
 tests
```

Let me know whether this can answer your question.

Comment: I have some png files as well as the wkhtmltopdf.exe file that I would like to utilize with a deployed function, are these the things that would be included in the "shared_code" folder?